# Always returns error 403 - Claims - Policies

Tags: c#, api, claims

I checked the database and the rules are all right, the user has access all right,however when it will access list in the API, it is always returning error 403.

Policy:

```
 public class ListStockPolicy
{
    public const string Name = "LIST_STOCK";
    public static ListStockClaims Claims = new ListStockClaims();
}

 public class ClaimsStock
{
    public class WriteStockClaims
    {
        public string Type => "Platform.Api.WRITE_STOCK";
        public string Value => "true";
    }

    public class ListStockClaims
    {
        public string Type => "Platform.Api.LIST_STOCK";
        public string Value => "true";
    }
}
```

PoliciesRegistry

```
  #region Stock
        options.AddPolicy(WriteStockPolicy.Name, policy => policy.RequireClaim(WriteStockPolicy.Claims.Type));
        options.AddPolicy(ListStockPolicy.Name, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ListStockPolicy.Claims.Type));
        #endregion
```

I don't know what it's going to be, it must be silly, but I can't figure it out.

Controller:

```
  [HttpGet]
    [Route("get/list")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer", Policy = ListStockPolicy.Name)]
```

All the rules work perfectly, only this one that I ended and include that gives this error.

In the database was created as well

[image]

I've tried changing taking out the Menu, but no way it allows even having access.
[image]

Comment: What is your URL (HTTP or HTTPS)?  I suspect you are using HTTP and server want a secure HTTPS.

Comment: I use the same logic for all but do not know what's going on, I'm using localhost for testing

Comment: 403 means you are not connecting to the server.  So I think the server wants HTTPS and you are send HTTP.

Comment: @jdweng I checked and it's all right anyway, it's something with the rules, probably

Comment: This has nothing to do with the database.  It is an issue with the HTTP Request not connecting the the server.

Comment: I checked and it's all right anyway, it's something with the rules, probably @jdweng

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs